# Paytm payment gateway integeration Andorid signed APK issue

Tags: android-studio, payment-gateway

After integration of Paytm payment gateway Android native app, debug mode app is working fine but signed APK was crashed when enter OTP and get response.

now only I got exact issue,
call back method "onTransactionResponse" get response successfully. I need to navigate to another activity so am using intent for that success response. that time below issue occure

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method wrap(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/b/c; or its super classes
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and error messages. Otherwise, it would very difficult to know what is wrong

Comment: ensure that not using sandbox account while taking release build

Comment: paytm also need sandbox account for release build. sandbox for paypal right ?